# Does Emgu.CV.Capture.QueryFrame leak memory?

Tags: vb.net, opencv, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2015, emgucv

Config:
Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, Project is Windows Forms, VB, with EmguCV's OpenCV wrappers.

My project has a reference to *emgu.cv.world*

My code is pretty simple (VB):

```
Imports Emgu.CV

Class Form1
    Public gStop As Boolean
    Async Function DoStuff() As Task
        Dim cap As New Capture
        Do While gStop = False
            cap.QueryFrame()
        Loop
    End Function
End Class
```

When I run DoStuff in the debugger, memory is consumed up to 2GB, then:

*Exception thrown: 'Emgu.CV.Util.CvException' in Emgu.CV.World.dll*

[Graph of Memory Leak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb9qA.png)

Am I right in thinking this clearly demonstrates a memory leak? My initial code did a bit more with the captured video than the above code does but I pared it down to try to isolate the leak. All the above code does now is retrieve a frame from the webcam and discard it, indefinitely. It puzzles me because this is really basic functionality for Emgu so I don't understand why it hasn't already been fixed and wonder if I've got something wrong somewhere. I haven't coded since VB6: used to know my onions but less so now.

Comment: OK so I didn't answer the question as originally posed but I did discover that QueryFrame is a fairly pointless function anyway. More elegant is to use this:
`AddHandler cap.ImageGrabbed, AddressOf ProcessFrame`
...
`cap.Start()`
...
`cap.Retrieve(m)`

Comment: This seems to work without the apparent memory leak.